# scoop doest give the same outcome

Tags: r, scoped

```
  nrow(filter(dataframe, fracture_type_1 == 1)) +
  nrow(filter(dataframe, fracture_type_2 == 1)) +
  nrow(filter(dataframe, fracture_type_3 == 1)) +
  nrow(filter(dataframe, fracture_type_4 == 1)) +
  nrow(filter(dataframe, fracture_type_5 == 1))
```

I want to make :

```
nrow(filter_at(dataframe, vars(starts_with("fracture_type_")), any_vars(.==1)))
```

but they dont give the same outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an output which is similar to your first attempt it would be :

```
library(dplyr)

dataframe %>%
    summarise(total = sum(select(., starts_with("fracture_type_")) == 1))
```